# How to be safe against XSS attacks but allowing <br>

Tags: php, mysql, xss

**At first an example of my database table:**

```
+----+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| id | user_id   | text                                |
+----+-----------+-------------------------------------+
| 12 | 45        | Hi, <br>this is an example. <br>Bye |
+----+-----------+-------------------------------------+
```

I always use MySQLi prepared statements, so SQL injections are no problem anymore, isn't it?

**Now the problem with XSS attacks:**

I want to display text out of a database table safely, so a common method would be `htmlentities` with `ENT_QUOTES` like this:

```
htmlentities($ValueFromDatabase, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

But I don't want to escape the `<br>` tags which are in the database.

How can escape all dangerous things but `<br>`? Or is there another method for displayig break lines (with database)?

**EDIT: Possible solution?**

```
//------INSERTING------
if (isset($userinput) AND $userinput != "") {
    $userinput = $_POST['userinput'];
} else {
    //Error Handling
    exit;
}

$userinput2 = nl2br($userinput);
$userinput3 = str_replace("<br />","[br]",$userinput2);

$sql = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO table (col1) VALUES (?)');
$sql->bind_param('s', $userinput3);
$sql->execute();

//------DISPLAYING------
$sql = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT userinput FROM table WHERE userid = ?');
$sql->bind_param('i', $userid);
$sql->execute();
$sql->store_result();
$sql->bind_result($userinput);
$sql_rows = $sql->num_rows;

if ($sql_rows != 0) {
    while ($sql->fetch()) {
        echo str_replace("[br]","<br />",htmlentities($userinput, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
    }
} else {
    echo'No rows in the database.';
}
```

Comment: Nope. My problem isn't the sql part, more the displaying-user-input part but allowing `<br>`.

Comment: Then please edit your title to *How to keep <br> and be safe from SQL injections or XSS?*

Comment: [strip_tags()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) allows you to whitelist a set of tags that won't be stripped

Comment: Is this safe against all possible xss?

Comment: @KlippOhei Nope, strip_tags is useless against XSS

Comment: I think this is a good question

Comment: @KlippOhei what you can do is convert the `<br/>` to `[br]` then parse it as `<br/>` on output.

Answer (score 0):

You should really try http://htmlpurifier.org/
It is good library, designed to prevent XSS, and it still allows some tags like **<br>**, <b>, <i> and other safe tags.